# Meaning of $\rho$ in this equation?

Tags: analysis

I am trying to understand how channel estimation in IEEE 802.11 works. For this, I am currently reading the 802.11 standard:

https://www.candelatech.com/downloads/802.11-2016.pdf

but I am failing at understand what $\rho[H_{BA,k}K_{B,k}]^T$ means (page 2395, formula 19-66).

Could somebody explain this formula to me?

Comment: it could mean the spectral radius of the matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius
the spectral radius is the maximum value of the absolute values of the eigenvalues of the matrix. It has this name because if the matrix is random and has a semicircular distribution, the spectral radius indicates the radius of this semicircle.

Comment: $\rho$ is defined on page $2393$ of the document as the value such that $H_{AB,k}=\rho[H_{BA,k}]^T$. A complex scalar